# IE <select> scrollTop

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, scrolltop

I have found that with a `select` element in IE (IE7 and IE9 anyway) where the `size` attribute is specified, using `.scrollTop` can result in some weird behavior.  I'm hoping there is a way around it.

If a user manually scrolls to a position, then a script scrolls it to another position, if the user clicks the up or down, the scrolling begins from the position before the script ran.

Here's a very simple example:

http://jsfiddle.net/7yHH7/

If you scroll manually, note the position, then "script" scroll with the button (one or more times), then start to manually scroll again, you'll notice in IE the scrolling begins where the manual scroll left off.

I would like to find a way to make IE work correctly.  I had hopes that jQuery's `.scrollTo()` might make things right, but unfortunately, no.

Comment: Occurs in IE8 too, but not Chrome19.

Comment: @Ash Thanks for checking that.  I should have mentioned that I know it works correctly in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure about the grammar with the .scrolltop function however, I do know that there are various jQuery scripts written for just that. @ http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex2/ there are some really nice scripts that may be worth having a look at. Sorry I couldn't help more than that.